# How to plot the derivative of an exponential function?

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[(1.8)^n, {n, 0.5, 10}]
```

Works fine, but this derivative gives an error and does not plot.

```
D[(1.8)^n, n] (* also ok *)
Plot[D[(1.8)^n, n], {n, 0.5, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 300, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

> General::ivar: 0.5000477864321607` is not a valid variable.

> General::ivar: 0.5477864798994975` is not a valid variable.

> General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.

How might I be able to change this?
The idea is to be able to plot something like this function and its derivative on the same plot.

```
 Plot[{(1.5)^n, D[(1.5)^n, n]}, {n, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to evaluate first, since Plot has holdall attribute.

```
    Plot[Evaluate[D[(18/10)^n, n]], {n, 0.5, 10}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Other methods.

```
Plot[D[(18/10)^n, n], {n, 0.5, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

```
Plot[Derivative[1][(18/10)^# &][n], {n, .5, 10}]
```

```
Plot[Derivative[1][Function[n, (18/10)^n]][x], {x, .5, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
Plot[D[(1.8)^n, n] /. {n -> x}, {x, 0.5, 10}]
```